# How does the Pytorch 2.0 compiler actually oparate during execution?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to machine learning and was just reading the official Pytorch 2.0 overview. I have some questions about the backend TorchInductor. "TorchInductor uses a pythonic define-by-run loop level IR to automatically map PyTorch models into generated Triton code on GPUs and C++/OpenMP on CPUs." What does "generate code" actually mean?

In the cpu case, does this mean the IR is mapped to explicit and readable c++ code, then compiled to machine code by some c++ compiler for execution? Or the IR is simply mapped to some c++-written functions in compiled libraries?

What about the gpu case? Does the Triton code written in python gets compiled to gpu machine code by Trition's built-in compiler?

Comment: Is there a _practical_ problem you're encountering, or is this just curiosity? (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask: *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"*).

Answer (score 0):

Yes C++ code or Triton code is generated from TorchInductor. The native C++ compiler or Triton compiler will further compile the generated code to native CPU or GPU code.